# MongoDB replication and EBS vs ephemeral

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, database-replication

I've read all of the MongoDB related documentation talking about the recommended practices for deploying Mongo on AWS, but I don't understand the recommendation to install on EBS with [RAID-10 (pdf)](http://info.mongodb.com/rs/mongodb/images/AWS_NoSQL_MongoDB.pdf) to avoid data loss.

This seems like admitting that replication doesn't work.  Why shouldn't one run Mongo using ephemeral drives and a cluster of 5 servers doing replication?

1. Performance is much greater and latency is predictable on local disks.
2. If a server goes down, the EBS backed store would have to be resynced with the replica anyway.  Sure you have the data, but it is already out of date.
3. Using EBS  makes for a much more complicated setup.  You need to use LVM or some other layer if you want to take snapshots, since EBS snapshots won't work across RAID.  You need to monitor and manage your RAID array and rebuild in the case of failure or if one of the EBS volumes has performance issues.

What exactly does using EBS protect against if one has backups and a large replica set?  It's almost admitting that replica sets won't protect you against dataloss.  (ignoring for the moment the race condition when writes have been sent to secondaries and a failure on the master happens before acknowledgements have been sent).

Answer (score 3):

> Why shouldn't one run Mongo using ephemeral drives and a cluster of 5 servers doing replication?

AWS is not perfect, it can have a network failure which results in the entire set being down. with ephemeral memory you would lose all your data. Plus block devices survive restarts of nodes.

That is a few things, I am sure there are more.

> If a server goes down, the EBS backed store would have to be resynced with the replica anyway.

Only after the point it went down, if that is a considerable amount of time then yes, it might be easier to copy the directory frm one replica to the other.

> Using EBS makes for a much more complicated setup. You need to use LVM or some other layer if you want to take snapshots, since EBS snapshots won't work across RAID.

You don't really need RAID within AWS itself, I mean they RAID each of your block devices and replica sets are good as throw away sets. You can get by with one block device per node.

> What exactly does using EBS protect against if one has backups and a large replica set?

It safe guards your sanity, restoring a backup of sizeable data across 10 odd members and resetting all the firewall/user permissions and OS etc etc could be...well...nasty.

I mean imagine having to re-setup your OS every single time you restart it.

> It's almost admitting that replica sets won't protect you against dataloss.

Hmm, you must have misread some where brecaue THAT is not what they guarantee. It is true that it is harder to lose data with repilica sets (if they are setup right) but they are actually designed to give High Availability (HA).

Backups and jornalling and other consistentcy methods are designed to not lose data.

Comment: I meant raid for performance 10 or just 0.  As for setting up my OS everytime i restart, i already do that with either Puppet or saltstack.  Thanks for spelling out relica sets.  I wish it was mentioned more times in the documentation that it's for HA and not dataloss.  Data inconsistency isn't the best thing when dealing with a DB.

Comment: @BradleyKreider tbh if I am totally, utterly, frank with you I actually use a hidden member or two for backups instead of actually taking backups. I haven't yet had data loss (I could since I have no backups). As for the RAID it will actually be less performant since it has to mirror to more disks so the performance of IO writes will be less than a single raid 0 disk. If you setup the OS already through puppet then my answer might be invalid

Answer (score 3):

So where do you see the recommendation to run RAID10 on EBS for mongodb? Their docs list it as an option but specifically recommend only EBS and Provisioned IOPS.

> For almost all deployments EBS will be the better choice. For production systems we recommend using
>
> - EBS-optimized EC2 instances
> - Provisioned IOPS (PIOPS) EBS volumes

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/

We run all of our mongodb instances at EC2 and all of them use EBS storage volumes with production instances using provisioned IO. Here's why:

1. Bringing back a failed member is faster. If an instance fails and needs to be stopped and restarted (not that frequent but it does happen) we can just detach the storage and re-attach it to another instance. Mongod comes up fine, recovers via the journal and then re-syncs with the primary for only the delta in data since the failure. This is a big deal when you have large data sets that may take many hours to restore from scratch. Storing the data on an ephemeral drive does not provide this capability.
2. Backups are easier (at least for replica sets under 1 TB). With a single EBS storage volume (up to 1 TB) we can take snapshots of a live secondary. As long as the journal is on the same storage volume the backup will be consistent. No need for a dedicated secondary for backups that has to be brought offline to backup.
3. No need for RAID except for multiple TB replica sets or for performance. EBS is already RAID behind the scenes for redundancy. We do use RAID when a replica set grows beyond 1 TB in storage but that's it and have not yet hit a point where a high IOPS EBS volume provides sufficient performance.
4. Provisioned IOPS give decent control of performance vs. cost. Being able to select EBS storage rated up to 4000 IOPS has allowed us to scale up performance for production systems (at higher cost) while still gaining the benefits of EBS storage. We use regular EBS volumes at lower cost for test systems.
5. Copying production data off for use in a test environment is much easier for large data sets. Snapshot the volumes, create a new storage volume from the snapshot and you're up and running.

I certainly can imagine future deployments using ephemeral storage (particularly as SSD costs drop) for certain high performance situations but EBS has been fairly reliable and dependable for us. Of course your experience and needs can and will differ but for us following the recommendation from MongoDB has served us well. In fact it's been reliable enough that for some environments we've moved to 1 Primary, 1 Secondary and an Arbiter, which helps with cost savings. Probably would not have done that without the ease of recovery and overall reliability of using EBS volumes on the Primary and Secondary.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.  I thought most people stripe EBS to get better performance out of it.  I was thinking the way to recover from a failed ephemeral drive would be to take the nightly backups on an EBS volume and have that as a starting point.

Comment: The Amazon link at the top of my post recommends RAID-10. "Use  
Provisioned  IOPS  EBS  volumes  in  RAID 10 MongoDB  is specifically  optimized  around  the  benefits  of  RAID10, and for  all  but  the  most  write heavy  workloads  it  is  the most  efficient  config"